# Как открыть файл или папку из java-приложения?

Tags: java, desktop

Каким образом можно открыть файл или папку, как будто мы открываем его через стандартный файловый браузер / Finder / и т.д.

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, точнее. Не вполне понятно, чего надо сделать-то…

Comment: Могу предложить варианты:
а) Вам нужен диалог открытия файла?
б) Вы хотите сэмулировать двойноё щелчёк по файлу в оболочке? Т.е. чтоыб он открылся так, будто юзер по нему дважды щёлкнул?

Comment: Например: у нас есть картинка и к ней в ОС привязан стандартный Windows Picture and Fax Viewer. Нужно из java-приложения запустить этот самый Viewer с открытой в нем картинкой. :)

Comment: Да, понятно.
Вам нужен аналог ShellExecute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Стоит обратить внимание на [Desktop API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html). Вот [статья](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html), подробно описывающая его.

Инициализация:

```
Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}
```

Открытие файла:

```
try {
    desktop.open(new File(fileName));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```